# Google Places API web service: how to set multiple types for Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using Place Autocomplete in Google Places API web service, following API calls work fine:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=palo&types=(regions)&components=country:us&key=API_KEY

But I need to have autocomplete for both **(regions)** and **address**, I use this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=palo&types=(regions)|address&components=country:us&key=API_KEY

It returns:

```
{
"predictions" : [],
"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

What is the correct way to set multiple types?

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

> If nothing is specified, all types are returned. In general only a
>   single type is allowed.